# How to store file with an absolute path?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can I store a file with the absolute path `/var/www/cityscape/public/storage/img/newyork.jpg`?

I tried `Storage::put()` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files), but this method seems to only accept relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path you've specified in your question is in the same system as your app you can use `File` instead:

```
File::put('/var/www/cityscape/public/storage/img/newyork.jpg', $theFile);
```

Hope this helps!